# How do I properly size these nested Iframes and a floating footer?

Tags: html, iframe, height, nested

I have a particular problem with nested `iframes`. This is a legacy application and I cannot change the way the `parent-iframe` is.

So I have a parent `iframe` in my main html doc.  This `parent-iframe` is the only child occupying the full html doc, hence we want the main html page to resize according to `parent-iframe` and show `scrollbars` when needed.

The `parent-iframe` decides which child `iframe` has to be shown and shows the `content-iframe`. This `content-iframe` will be the only child inside `parent-iframe`, meaning its content body height and width should be the deciding factor for `scrollbars` in the browser. They are already using jQuery to resize the `iframes` based on content height, but I can see something is wrong.

The source inside `content-iframe` will have a header `div`, content `div` and a footer `div`. The footer `div` should stick to the bottom of the browser window always.  If content is small, it should stay at the bottom of the window. If content is tall, it should be pushed down further to stay at the bottom of the page. I cannot get `$(window).height()` as it gets me the `content-iframe`'s height. It is very tricky to do this, and calculate heights because of the nested `iframes`.

I need ideas and a good solution for resizing.

```
   parentIframe
    contentIFrame
      mainDiv
        Header 
        Content
        Footer
```

### Edit:

Ok, I found a solution, not sure if thats right, but it works perfectly.
I had a parent div for the parentIframe, hence on load, I got the `$(window).height()` and set it as min-height for the `parentDiv`. Now in my `resizeIFrames` method, I set the `parentDiv's` min-height to the `parentIframe`, `contentIFrame` and `mainDiv's` min-height and then it all works fine.

Comment: can you please answer your own question so that people with similar issues would find it useful?

Comment: Hi acudars, please see my edit for the solution

Comment: I've seen your edit, it's just the question remains unanswered, if no separate answer is added, even if you answer it inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution, not sure if thats right, but it works perfectly.
I had a parent div for the parentIframe, hence on load, I got the `$(window).height()` and set it as min-height for the `parentDiv`. Now in my `resizeIFrames` method, I set the `parentDiv's` min-height to the `parentIframe`, `contentIFrame` and `mainDiv's` min-height and then it all works fine.